# Rename all files with a Windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, rename

I have a list of files like this:

```
1 (1).jpg
1 (2).jpg
1 (3).jpg
.
.
.
1 (100).jpg
```

What do I need is an automatic BAT-file which will rename them into a list like this:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
.
.
.
100.jpg
```

I wish someone could help me, because I searched a lot but I didn't understand.

Comment: Windows batch is not very good at string handling. Maybe you might opt for another technology, like Powershell?

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
for /L %%e in (1,1,100) do ren "1 (%%e).jpg" "%%e.jpg"
```

Assign `1 to 100` step 1 (see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation) to `%%e` then use `%%e` to rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested (you should execute it in the same directory):

```
for %%# in ("*).jpg") do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ("%%~n#") do (
     ren "%%~f#" "%%a.%%~x#"
  )
)
```